# How do you run a stored procedure or function in a CASE statement in a view?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I've got a view based on a series of `CASE` statements. One of the checks that I have to do is if a given column's value is 0 AND there exist any other records where certain columns are `NOT NULL` then return a string.

It looks like this:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN (Column1 = 0 AND EXEC CheckExistsNonTypeIncreases =  1) THEN 'Missing or invalid data' ELSE '' END AS IncreaseCheck
FROM MyTable1
```

`MyTable1` is made up of nullable money columns.

`CheckExistsNonTypeIncreases` looks like this:

```
DECLARE @Exists BIT

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [dbo].MyTable1 WHERE (Column2 IS NOT NULL OR
                                                                       Column3 IS NOT NULL OR
                                                                       Column4 IS NOT NULL OR
                                                                       Column5 IS NOT NULL OR
                                                                       Column6 IS NOT NULL))
BEGIN
    SET @Exists = 1
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @Exists = 0
END

RETURN @Exists
```

Views can't have variables so I can't run the SP that does the check in advance. I also can't embed the `EXEC` statement into the `CASE`. Is there any way to run `CheckExistsNonTypeIncreases` in the `CASE` statement? I don't mind changing `CheckExistsNonTypeIncreases` to a function if that will work but I can't alter the view except for this one `CASE`. Only reason I made it a stored procedure is functions require a parameter and this does not.

EDIT --

Figured it out, it wasn't working when I made it into a function because I wasn't using the [dbo] prefix.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  You should make the stored procedure into a function.  They don't require arguments.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Added some more detail about the table and `CheckExistsNonTypeIncreases`

Comment: So you "solved" this or not? It reads more like a stream of consciousness than a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way to run CheckExistsNonTypeIncreases in the CASE
>   statement?

No.  (actually CASE is an expression, not at statement, which kind of explains why not).  What you could do, is refactor the proc into a function and use that.